# Using UDFs in Tables

Tags: vba, excel

My workbook involves a rather extensive, dynamic table that includes cells who's values are calculated by UDF (ie, the cell value is =myFunc()). Cells like these are referenced by other cells in the same table, which also take it into a UDF.

I experienced a catastrophic failure a couple of days ago while editing a function and thought I fixed the issue. But upon loading the file on another computer, they experienced the catastrophic failure upon the 2nd launch of the file.

I read: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/bug-report-automation-error-catastrophic-failure/6c8d4d86-0dc9-4f8f-ab9c-a5537d5c1d3e?db=5

Unfortunately there is no feedback.

My question:
Is it alright to use UDFs in this manner in tables? Any suggested alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it alright to use UDFs in this manner in tables?

Yes. While [structured tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E) can be treated as a [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197604.aspx), they can also be referenced by converntional xlR1C1 or xlA1 cell addresses.

> Any suggested alternatives?

A better coded UDF would be my first suggestion. Suggestions may be offered but you've provided no actual code for examination and testing. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).